# How can you detect when files are dropped into Windows Explorer?

Tags: c#, .net, drag-and-drop

I have a WinForms app that has a TreeView. The user can drag files from WindowsExplorer to the TreeView, and then they can drag the files back into WindowsExplorer which in affect copies the files to wherever the files were dropped. What I'm trying to do is, if the files already exist in the directory where the files are being dropped, I want to rename the files/folders being copied in ahead of time, so that there's no collision.

Here's how I'm copying files into WindowsExplorer. On the treeView's ItemDrag, I loop through the nodes of the selected node, and then package that into an array. Then, I use this code:

```
        var dataObject = new DataObject(DataFormats.FileDrop, files.ToArray());
        dataObject.SetData(DataFormats.StringFormat, dataObject);
        DoDragDrop(dataObject, DragDropEffects.Copy);
```

This works well, but once it ships off to Windows Explorer, it's out of my hands. How can I find out when and where the files are being copied TO and intercept that to make changes? Is this possible?

Comment: You'd want to check out this article - http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/explorerdragdrop.aspx - for a C++ way of doing this. It might help.

Answer (score 1):

[Explorer Drag & Drop](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/Explorer_Drag_Drop.aspx) is an excellent article doing what you are trying to achieve.

EDIT2: It seems that there's a [C++ article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/explorerdragdrop.aspx) available for the same on CodeProject. But I was unable to find a way of how to do it using C#.

Comment: That doesn't cover the main problem I'm having. If you try to drag from the listbox in his example back into explorer, you get prompted by windows like you normally would. I want to avoid that, and automatically rename files.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no way to know drop target (in your case destination folder). You can look into [CFSTR_FILENAMEMAP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776902%28VS.85%29.aspx#CFSTR_FILENAMEMAP) shell clipboard format, but still in this case you can only provide name mappings before (or in process) of drag-n-drop.

Also note, that default DataObject in .net has limited shell support. So if you need to use mentioned above format, you need to write your own IDataObject implementation (or take someone's implementation, good example with lot shell drag-n-drop related stuff can be found [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/adamroot/pages/shell-style-drag-and-drop-in-net-wpf-and-winforms.aspx))

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting the file names into the dataobject, create a temporary file with a unique/easily distinguishable name and place that file name into the data object's drop list instead (That file could be empty or contain some information you might need). Use a FileSystemWatcher (watching an entire drive) to detect the drop (set the filter to the temporary file name, set IncludeSubDirectories to true, and set Path to root directory of drive to watch.) Initiate the DoDragDrop. Once the unique/easily distinguishable file is dropped, the FileSystemWatcher can tell you where it was dropped and you can do whatever you need to do (e.g. delete the dropped temporary file and replace with the ones you originally wanted to drop. It is a far-from-perfect solution but might help. Better still, it might give someone an idea to come up with a better one!)

One downside is that you don't really know in which drive someone might drop the file and you may have to set up a watcher for several drives. And if you miss a drive (or a network path) then problems .....!  Remember to dispose of the watchers after the drop.

There has to be a better way though. e.g. consider when you drag a file from a zip folder. The file is only extracted after the drop.

Answer (score -2):

i don't think that is possible.